# Which are the control points to create (approximate) a circle using 8 cubic bezier curves

Tags: cocoa, math, geometry, uibezierpath, bezier

**The premises**

I have a circle that animates into a shape made out of 8 bezier curves. For the transition to be smooth, I need the circle to also be made out of 8 cubic bezier curves.
Here's what I have so far:

**The code**

```
- (UIBezierPath*)pathBubbleLeft {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:p(sqlx, sqlMidy)];

    CGFloat r = sqlW/2;
    CGFloat sin45 = 0.7071 * r;
    CGFloat cos45 = 0.7071 * r;

    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx - cos45, sqlMidy - sin45) control1:vector(0, 0.4) control2:vector(0.5, 0.8)];
    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx, sqly) control1:vector(0.2, 0.5) control2:vector(0.4, 1)];

    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx + cos45, sqlMidy - sin45) control1:vector(0.6, 0) control2:vector(0.8, 0.5)];
    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMaxx, sqlMidy) control1:vector(0.5, 0.2) control2:vector(1, 0.5)];

    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx + cos45, sqlMidy + sin45) control1:vector(0, 0.4) control2:vector(0.5, 0.8)];
    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx, sqlMaxy) control1:vector(0.2, 0.5) control2:vector(0.4, 1)];

    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx - cos45, sqlMidy + sin45) control1:vector(0.6, 0) control2:vector(0.8, 0.5)];
    [path addRelativeCurveToPoint:point(sqlx, sqlMidy) control1:vector(0.5, 0.2) control2:vector(1, 0.5)];

    return path;
}
```

the path starts from left and goes clockwise (from pi to pi/2, 0, 3pi/4, pi)

`point` and `vector` are shorts for CGPointMake and CGVectorMake

'sql' in `sqlx`, `sqly`, `sqlMidx`, `sqlMidY`, `sqlMaxx` & `sqlMaxy` stands for 'squareLeft', the bounding rect of the circle. These are all CGFloats.

`addRelativeCurveToPoint` is used to define the control points relatively to the start/end points. (0,0) is start, (1,1) is end. Easier to read.

```
- (void)addRelativeCurveToPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint control1:(CGVector)controlPoint1 control2:(CGVector)controlPoint2 {
    CGPoint start = self.currentPoint;
    CGPoint end = endPoint;
    CGFloat x1 = start.x + controlPoint1.dx*(end.x - start.x);
    CGFloat x2 = start.x + controlPoint2.dx*(end.x - start.x);
    CGFloat y1 = start.y + controlPoint1.dy*(end.y - start.y);
    CGFloat y2 = start.y + controlPoint2.dy*(end.y - start.y);
    [self addCurveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint1:CGPointMake(x1, y1) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(x2, y2)];
}
```

**The results so far:**
[image: static]

The red circle is a bit wavy. That's what I'd like to fix.

Below, the left circle uses the above code, the right circle is made out of 4 curves with 2 zero length insertions at the top and 2 at the bottom (`[path addLineToPoint:path.currentPoint];`).

[image]

The transition is ok from the left one to mid-peanut but weird from mid to the right

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using four segments, a circle approximation using cubic Bezier curves cannot get rounder than what it is with the 0.55228[...] value that @fang gave you in a comment: it is simply the mathematically only value at which a cubic Bezier curve best approximates a circle. In infinite precision representation, it's actually the value that you get from:

```
     4        angle       4                     sqrt(2) - 1
k =  - * tan(-------)  =  - * tan(pi/8)  =  4 * -----------
     3          2         3                          3
```

and is 0.5522847498307933984022516322796[...]. This gets you the best possible approximation with 4 segments, so if you need to use 8 segments, we need a different value, which means we need to use the derivation that gives us *k* for an angle of pi/2 (a quarter circle), and see what it gives us for pi/4 (an eighth circle). So: we plug the angle `pi/4` into the functions outlined in this [Primer on Bezier Curve](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo)'s section on [approximating circles with cubic curves](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic), and we get:

```
start = {
  x: 1,
  y: 0
}

c1 = {
  x: 1,
  y: 4/3 * tan(pi/16)
}

c2 = {
  x: cos(pi/4) + 4/3 * tan(pi/16) * sin(pi/4)
  y: sin(pi/4) - 4/3 * tan(pi/16) * cos(pi/4)
}

e = {
  x: cos(pi/4)
  y: sin(pi/4)
}
```

which gives us these (entirely useful) approximated coordinates:

```
s  = (1,           0)
c1 = (1,           0.265216...)
c2 = (0.894643..., 0.51957...)
e  = (0.7071...,   0.7071...)
```

That'll be segment 1, and then the rest of the segments are simply derived through symmetry, with segment 2 being:

```
s  = (0.7071...,   0.7071...)
c1 = (0.51957...,  0.894643...)
c2 = (0.265216..., 1)
e  = (0,           1)
```

A demonstration of these coordinates used overlayed a quarter circle is here: http://jsbin.com/ridedahixu/edit?html,output

And the rest are the obvious symmetries in the (+,-), (-,+), and (-,-) quadrants.

These are the **best possible approximations**, so: if `bezierPathWithOvalInRect(...)` does something else, it's being *less correct* than values we worked out decades ago =)

Comment: This is a neat answer. I'm updating the question with the final code, for the lazy. Cheers!

Comment: According to [this article](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/), this is **not the best possible approximation**; it can be improved by ~28%

Comment: This is an... unsatisfactory page. Why are we not given the true value, but only an approximation? If this is your page, can you add the true symbolic function for that value?

Answer (score 1):

When circle is approximated by four Bezier curve, the first control point (after (1,0) starting point) has coordinates (1, 0.552). For 8-curve case it will (1, 0.276) due to Bezies subdividing rules.

So your control vectors are **(0, 0.276), (0.276, 0), (0.195, 0.195)** with different sign combinations

Comment: If you need a more precise value, it is 0.552284749.

Comment: Did a test with 0.552284749 http://i.imgur.com/A8T3oaB.png . The circle is rounder, but still does not perfectly match bezierPathWithOvalInRect (red stroke). I'll leave it for a few more days before accepting the answer, maybe there are other ways. 

For what I needed (the animation gets scalled down to a ~ 40x40px bounding rect) its more than enough in the current form, but I'm still curious :). Thanx @MBo & fang for the fast replies!

Comment: @fang I posted a test result above, but looks like I can only tag one user per comment :|

Comment: According to the accepted answer, the value would be 0.26521648983954... and not 0.276 as stated here. I've done a test with Illustrator and the value of 0.265 gives very precise results.

Comment: @Marco Luglio My value is calculated for the half of roughly divided Pi/2 arc, and Mike value  - for true Pi/4 arc, so his one should be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

*Based on Mike's answer*

```
- (CGRect)sql {
    return CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frameHeight, self.frameHeight);
}

CGPoint point(CGFloat x, CGFloat y) {return CGPointMake(x, y);}

#define sqlx (self.sql.origin.x)
#define sqly (self.sql.origin.y)
#define sqlMaxx (self.sql.origin.x + self.sql.size.width)
#define sqlMidx (self.sql.origin.x + self.sql.size.width/2)
#define sqlMaxy (self.sql.origin.y + self.sql.size.height)
#define sqlMidy (self.sql.origin.y + self.sql.size.height/2)
#define sqlW (self.sql.size.width)
#define sqlH (self.sql.size.height)


- (UIBezierPath*)pathBubbleLeft {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:p(sqlx, sqlMidy)];

    CGFloat r = sqlW/2;
    CGFloat sin45 = sin(M_PI_4)*r;
    CGFloat cos45 = cos(M_PI_4)*r;

    CGFloat magic1 = (cos(M_PI_4) + 4/3.0 * tan(M_PI/16.0) * sin(M_PI_4))*r;
    CGFloat magic2 = (sin(M_PI_4) - 4/3.0 * tan(M_PI/16.0) * cos(M_PI_4))*r;
    CGFloat magic3 = 4/3.0 * tan(M_PI/16.0)*r;

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx - cos45, sqlMidy - sin45)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlx, sqlMidy - magic3)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx - magic1, sqlMidy - magic2)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx, sqly)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx - magic2 , sqlMidy - magic1)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx - magic3, sqly)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx + cos45, sqlMidy - sin45)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx + magic3, sqly)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx + magic2 , sqlMidy - magic1)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMaxx, sqlMidy)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx + magic1 , sqlMidy - magic2)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMaxx, sqlMidy - magic3)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx + cos45, sqlMidy + sin45)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMaxx, sqlMidy + magic3)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx + magic1 , sqlMidy + magic2)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx, sqlMaxy)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx + magic2 , sqlMidy + magic1)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx + magic3, sqlMaxy)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlMidx - cos45, sqlMidy + sin45)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx - magic3 , sqlMaxy)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlMidx - magic2 , sqlMidy + magic1)];

    [path addCurveToPoint:point(sqlx, sqlMidy)
            controlPoint1:point(sqlMidx - magic1 , sqlMidy + magic2)
            controlPoint2:point(sqlx, sqlMidy + magic3)];

    return path;
}
```

Result:
 Light gray is pathBubbleLeft, red stroke is bezierPathWithOvalInRect (imho this is perfect).

[image]

*Observations:*

*This code works for iOS, for which the coordinates (0,0) are top left and (320,548) are bottom right. For MacOS (0,0) is bottom left;*

*The drawing starts at 9 o'clock and goes clockwise;*